# SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager - Store nvarchar data greater than 4000 characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager. I'm having trouble with storing some data in a column. The column has a data type of nvarchar, with a length of 4000, which I've now learned is the max length you can have.

I need to store data in the column that is longer than 4000 characters...is there a way to increase the size? Or is there another way to store it?

Comment: nvarchar(max) wasn't introduced until the 2005 version

Comment: @Gabriel, totally missed the "2000" part in the title.  Not sure how. :(

Comment: @Gabriel, totally missed the "2000" part in the title.  Not sure how. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in SQL Server 2000, the only 2 ways to increase it would be:

- Use the data type VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR (VARCHAR's limit is 8000, where NVARCHAR's is 4000)  NVARCHAR is the unicode version of VARCHAR.
- Use the TEXT or NTEXT datatypes.  TEXT stores the value outside of your table, and can store up to 2^31 - 1 characters.  NTEXT can store up to 2^30 - 1 characters.

Comment: Thanks, switching it to VARCHAR should give me enough length to hold the data. Although, I'm getting a warning when I try to change the column data type: Warning: Data may be lost converting column 'MyColumn' from 'nvarchar(4000)'. Is there a way to convert it without losing the data?

Comment: That is only a warning.  The loss is a possibility depending on your data.  If you know that your data does not have unicode characters, then don't worry about it.  Convert it anyway.

Comment: @Steven - You'd need to check that you don't have any characters that will be lost in the conversion (Maybe try a query `where CAST(yourCol AS varchar(4000)) <> YourCol` and see if it returns any results)

Answer (score 3):

First, follow @Gabriel's advice if you can live with 8000 non-Unicode characters.

In places where older versions of our app needed to store larger text strings, we allocated multiple fields (`textvar`, `textvar2`, ...) and had standard application components to split & concatenate them where they were used.  Otherwise, you can use a blob & convert as needed. Ugly but functional.

Comment: That's how `syscomments` dealt with that issue as well (of course it makes searching with `LIKE` more problematic as the search text could be split over a boundary)

Comment: +1, I'd go with multiple split columns before attempting to use the now deprecated TEXT or NTEXT mess.