# Max NVARCHAR length

Tags: sql-server-2000

I am waiting a stored procedure that creates a script more than 4000 characters in SQL Server 2000. I am using `NVARCHAR (4000)` but when I use `NVARCHAR (MAX)` I am getting this error.

What type can I use for this …. ?

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Sxxxx, Line 19
>   Line 19: Incorrect syntax near 'MAX'.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_ Sxxxx, Line 109
>   Must declare the variable '@ExecuteScript'.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure sp_ Sxxxx, Line 113
>   Must declare the variable '@ExecuteScript'.

Comment: `SQL 2000` doesn't exist as far as I know; I think you mean `SQL Server 2000`, which actually has a tag here. Tag information also doesn't go in the subject - that's the reason we have tags. :-) The tag system works extremely well here. Please don't try and help it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager - Store nvarchar data greater than 4000 characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916451/sql-server-2000-enterprise-manager-store-nvarchar-data-greater-than-4000-chara). NVarChar(MAX) wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2005.

Comment: sure will do next time.... thanks

Answer (score 3):

The MAX keyword is new to SQL Server 2005 and above which is why you are receiving the syntax error. Since you are using SQL Server 2000 you will want to use text, ntext or image data types. Have a look at the docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174534(v=sql.80).aspx